# What is the fastest way to dynamically generate a list in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, performance, list, jquery-mobile, dynamically-generated

I am creating a jQuery mobile app where UI events generate lists on the fly. So the faster I can make these lists come up the more responsive my UI will appear. I've outlined a few approaches below. My hope is that people with expertise on web performance can either tell me which approach they think is best or suggest an entirely new approach.

Approach #1 "Programaticaly Generate

selectors from an array of list element objects"

```
$.each(array, function(index, value){
var listElement = "$(<li></li>)";
listElement.text(array.elementName);
//Do some other stuff to listElement
$("#displayedList").append(listElement);
//append to Displayed List
});
```

Approach #2 "Clone

elements from dom object from an array of list element objects"

```
$.each(array, function(index, value){
var listElement = $("#listElementTemplate").clone();
//Cloned list element from already loaded dom element
listElement.text(array.elementName);
//Do some other stuff to listElement
$("#displayedList").append(listElement);
//append to Displayed List
});
```

Approach #3 "Display already loaded list in an iframe"

```
$("#displayedListWrapper").find("iframe").src("#loadedList");
```

Comment: I believe first approach is the best as you can easily modify contents before injecting them into DOM. All you need is to call `.listview('refresh')` to enhance their markup. Approach #2 cloning, copies enhanced markup and make it a bit difficult to modify as you'll need to go deeper into the enhanced markup to do changes.

Comment: Hi @omar I don't anticipate modification or css refreshment being an issue in any of the scenarios. My primary concern is speed.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/4qH6E/ click on anytime to get time elapsed of creating 1000 list item.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsPerf I made for your scenarios : http://jsperf.com/dynamic-li

#### Setup

Here's the sample JSON I used for this :

```
[
    "Sweet Child 'O Mine",
    "Summer of '69",
    "Smoke in the Water",
    "Enter Sandman",
    "I thought I've seen everything",
    "Never Hear Surf Music Again",
    "The Canyon",
    "Liberation Begins",
    "Touch of the Sun",
    "Lovely Day",
    "Ca Plane Pour Moi",
    "Liberation In A Dream",
    "If You Love Me (Really Love Me)",
    "Acid Darbari",
    "R.I.P.",
    "Festival",
    "If I Rise",
    "Liberation",
    "Nocturne No. 2 in E flat"
]
```

And the test methods used are :

```
   //Scenario #1 : Programmatically generate li elements
   function makeLiProgrammatically() {
       $.each(songs, function (i, song) {
           var listElement = $("<li></li>");
           listElement.text(song);
           $list.append(listElement);
       });
       $list.listview("refresh");
   }
   //Scenario #2 : Clone DOM <li> element
   function cloneDOMLi() {
       $.each(songs, function (i, song) {
           var listElement = $("#listElementTemplate").clone();
           //Cloned list element from already loaded dom element
           listElement.text(song);
           //Do some other stuff to listElement
           $list.append(listElement);
           //append to Displayed List
       });

       $list.listview("refresh");
   }
   //Extra scenario - replacing each loop with for loop in scenario #1
   function makeLiProgrammaticallyForLoop() {
       for (; i < songs.length; i++) {
           var listElement = $("<li></li>");
           listElement.text(songs[i]);
           $list.append(listElement);
       };
       $list.listview("refresh");
   }
```

The last scenario is my addition, just to check if `for`  is better than `each` in this scenario. And the results are.. **drumroll**

#### Results

[image: jsPerf result]

<strike>It looks like adding `<li>` programmatically,</strike> with `for` loop <strike>was the fastest! The reason, as Omar mentioned, is simple. You're creating an element in memory, so it doesnt consume that much of memory. Whereas, in your scenario #2, you were going to the DOM, searching for the `li` element (that too, repeatedly), which slowed it up.</strike> - **See EDIT**

Hope this clears things up!

**PS** Dont mind the screwed up formatting in jsPerf, I think jQM screwed it up when I added it to the scripts.

#### EDIT

As Mathias pointed out, cloning a DOM object is the fastest! This is what I changed in scenario #2 :

```
//Scenario #2 : Clone DOM <li> element
       function cloneDOMLi() {
           var listElement = $("#listElementTemplate"); //pre cached the li so that it can be used again and again
           $.each(songs, function (i, song) {
               $list.append(listElement.clone().text(song));
           });

           $list.listview("refresh");
       }
```

And added an extra scenario :

```
 function cloneDOMLiForLoop() {
   for(;i<songs.length; i++){
       //Cloned list element from already loaded dom element
       $listElement.clone().text(songs[i]);
       //Do some other stuff to listElement
       $list.append($listElement);
       //append to Displayed List
     };
}
```

It looks like caching the DOM `li` did the trick! And as mentioned in the previous (wrong) observation, `for` is faster than `each` in this case as well. Results :

[image: revised jsPerf]

**EDIT 1**
I added one more test which creates `<li></li>` only once, and clones it in the loop. And of course using `for` loop. Here's the code :

```
function makeLiProgrammaticallyOnceForLoop() {
     var li = $("<li></li>");
     for(;i<songs.length; i++){
       $list.append(li.clone().text(songs[i]));
     };
     $list.listview("refresh");
}
```

And here are the results :

[image]

Looks like programmatically creating `li` and reusing it through `clone` is *also* fast. So these would go without saying :

1. You could either create an element dynamically, or get it from the DOM
2. Pre-cache your element and re-use by `clone`.
3. Use `for` instead of `each` if you want good performance.

   **Important** I didnt mention i-frame approach in tests because for mobile phones, especially the ones running Android OS 2.3.7, there is a clunky implementation of i-frames in the native browser, its always good to avoid them, even though that might be the fastest one of your scenarios.

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you cache `$("#listElementTemplate")` in the second test case (outside the loop)? I would think that gives a better comparison between creating versus cloning a new element, the DOM lookup might be skewing the results.

Comment: Fascinating, although I find it hard to believe that the difference between a regular `for` loop and a `$.each` loop is *that big*. [Other tests](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/73) show a more moderate difference.

Comment: Ah, I see: you missed the `$list.listview("refresh");` in your last test. That probably makes quite a difference!

Comment: @MattiasBuelens just added `listview(refresh)` and added some more tests, take a look! Maybe its my browser, `for` has always been faster than `each`. Im using chrome 28.

Comment: Strange. I [slightly reworked your tests](http://jsperf.com/dynamic-li/3) (moved stuff from setup to preparation and removed the jQuery Mobile CSS) and I get varying results (on Firefox).

Comment: @MattiasBuelens jquerymobile's css is vastly important to this test because, when `refresh` happens, jqm's js talks to jqm's css. so having that in test is vital

Comment: Ah, that might explain it, I thought I could just leave it out. Fair enough!